# Conditional variation in wordpress woocommrce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a WordPress eCommerce website, where the chosen shopping platform is WooCommerce.

I would like the ability to hide other size product variations but cannot seem to find a solution, anywhere on the Internet.

For example, say I have a canvas wall arts Shop whereby the website sells wall arts. Product image Menu is as follows:
[variation attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUBTx.jpg)

example:
if 1 piece is selected only 1 piece size show

- 1 piece

1. small
2. medium
3. large

when 3 piece selected only 3 piece size show

- 3 piece

  1. small
  2. medium
  3. large
  4. xl

when 5 piece selected only 5 piece size show

- 5 piece

  1. small
  2. medium
  3. large

Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: Thats variable product. If customer wants different size for second, third, etc will just add each individualy.

Comment: https://legendarywallart.net/products/custom-horizontal-canvas-set?variant=12123406499897

thanks for your response but i need this type of condition

Comment: Maybe check this plugin - https://woocommerce.com/products/composite-products/. This is not the place to write codes freely. If you still want to do it yourself check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/352171/187933

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.